# Nearest blocks, one of each color, but on different rows

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, traveling-salesman

Let's say that I have a room with 3 different colors of blocks, labelled A, B, and C:
[image: Picture 1]

My goal is to find the three blocks closest to Lolo such that I have one A, one B, and one C.  Additionally, each block and Lolo himself must be on different rows:
[image: Picture 2]

For example, no block on Row 1 may be used, since Lolo is on that row:
[image: Picture 3]

If we pick the A block above Lolo, no other block from Row 0 can be used:
[image: Picture 4]

For this example, the correct answer is these blocks:
[image: Picture 5]

I can easily find the closest three blocks to Lolo; however, I'm having a hard time applying the additional constraints (one of each letter, not on same row).  This feels like a variation of the travelling salesman problem.

What is an efficient way of figuring out these blocks?  (Even a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!)  Thanks!

Comment: I could brute force it by taking each subset of 3 blocks, calculating the additive distance to Lolo, sort that by distance ascending, then test each subset for the additional constraints.  Surely there has to be a more elegant way though :)

Comment: Does "A" have to be closer to Lolo than "C" ?  Or are there  constraints on the ordering of the closeness of the blocks?  IE, does "A" have to be closest, followed by "B", followed by "C"?

Comment: "A" can be further from Lolo than "C".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Greedy solution:**

All picking of blocks below should be done such that it adheres to the row constraints.

1. Pick the closest block not already picked (say this is an A).
2. Pick the closest non-A block (say this is an B).
3. Pick the closest non-A, non-B (thus C) block.
4. Record this distance.
5. If there was a closer C in the same row as B, pick that C, along with the next closest B and record the distance.

   - For more than 3 colors, you'd want to just pick the next closest B in a different row.
6. Stop if the closest unpicked block is further than `bestDistanceSoFar/3`, otherwise repeat from 1.
7. Return the best distance.

For this I'd suggest having a sorted list for each colour.

I believe this is optimal, but why it would be requires some thought.

**Preprocess:**

You can remove all blocks in the same row as Lolo, as you mentioned, but also all blocks further from Lolo than another block of the same type in the same row, which is not a lot in this case, but still.

[image: Pic]

**Additional note:**

Given that you only have 3 colours, the running time of brute force will be O(n<sup>3</sup>), which is quite a lot less than the O(n!) or O(2<sup>n</sup>) of the TSP.

The obvious optimization to the brute force is to separate all the colours, which will result in a running time of O(n<sub>1</sub>n<sub>2</sub>n<sub>3</sub>) where n<sub>i</sub> is the amount of blocks with the i-th colour.

Comment: Seems like you can improve this algorithm by using a 2D k-d tree and using that to find the nearest neighbor for each color/letter. Seems like it should limit the algorithm to O(N log N), with a perhaps somewhat high coefficient (from construction of multiple kd-trees and removing multiple points).

Comment: Thanks!  It turns out that the preprocess technique alone removed enough blocks that my existing brute force solution became fast enough.

Comment: @Nuclearman I think a kd-tree might be complicating things a bit much. A list sorted by euclidean distance from Lolo should be sufficient.

Comment: @Dukeling: You are correct for what the question asks as is. However, it seems likely that there will be multiple queries with changes in Lolo's position and perhaps blocks removed in which case, a k-d tree can potentially limit the algorithm from O(k*(N log N)) to O((N+k)log N), where k is the number of queries. Although, if there are not much more blocks than are shown in the example, then your approach is probably sufficient. In any case, it seems good to at least mention the possibility of using a k-d tree in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use DFS

You build the G in the next way :

1. Lolo is the root
2. Choose available block  that is not have color that already visit, add to G with weight is the distance from Lolo
3. Make all block on the same row as un-available
4. If there are more available blocks Go to 2
5. If no available blocks go back Lolo, and choose block that is not direct son of Lolo

After you build the graph you can run DFS with depth 3 and choose the  lowest cost path.

This will give you the lowest distance.

There are other constrains ? how fast does it need to run ?

Comment: Choosing the other answer for the preprocess technique that it mentioned (that we ended up using), but upvoting this.  Thanks!